# Component doesn't have correct name in chrome react devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I inspect my application on production via React Dev Tools in chrome, the component name shows up as `ComponentName_ComponentName`. While running app locally the problem doesn't occur. What might be the reason of this?

The component is stateless functional component defined as

`export function ComponentName(props: SomeProps): JSX.Element {}`

Answer (score 0):

I think  names get removed in production as a way to reduce the weight of the bundle. I don't think you can resolve this , even using displayName as that's removed also.

Comment: Unless the CRA get's ejected

Comment: we are not talking about CRA here

Comment: CRA =  create-react-app ? Never used that.

Comment: The name is not removed but repeated with underscore inbetween. So this is weird in terms that other components names are correct in prod.